# Wildfly admin console cannot be open on Linux

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, jboss, wildfly

I installed wildfly 13 Final, edited standalone.xml , added users but I still can't open the admin console on Ubuntu 16. 
I try to get an access to the console remotely.

I can connect from the local machine, though

```
sudo curl -i http://localhost:9990/console/index.html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Thu, 31 May 2018 02:30:23 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 1241
Content-Type: text/html
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Sun, 01 Jul 2018 20:51:16 GMT
```

config - /etc/default/wildfly

```
    #################################################
# General configuration for the init.d scripts, #
# not necessarily for WildFly itself.           #
# default location: /etc/default/wildfly        #
#################################################

## Location of JDK
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre"

## Location of WildFly
JBOSS_HOME="/opt/wildfly"

## The username who should own the process.
JBOSS_USER=wildfly

## The mode WildFly should start, standalone or domain
JBOSS_MODE=standalone

## Configuration for standalone mode
JBOSS_CONFIG=standalone.xml

## Configuration for domain mode
# JBOSS_DOMAIN_CONFIG=domain.xml
# JBOSS_HOST_CONFIG=host-master.xml

## The amount of time to wait for startup
STARTUP_WAIT=60

## The amount of time to wait for shutdown
SHUTDOWN_WAIT=60

## Location to keep the console log
JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG="/var/log/wildfly/console.log"

## Additionals args to include in startup
# JBOSS_OPTS="--admin-only -b 127.0.0.1"
```

/opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml , here is some code

```
 <interface name="management">
      <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}" />
   </interface>
   <interface name="public">
      <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}" />
   </interface>
   <interface name="unsecure">
      <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:0.0.0.0}" />
   </interface>
</interfaces>
    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>
</server>
```

console.log below:

```
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /opt/wildfly

  JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true

=========================================================================

^[[0m21:07:29,814 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.8.5.Final
^[[0m^[[33m21:07:30,307 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server] (main) WFLYSRV0266: Server home is set to '/opt/wildfly/standalone', but server real home is '/opt/wildfly-13.0.0.Final/standalone' - unpredictable results may occur.
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:30,336 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.2.Final
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:30,366 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.3.2.Final
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:30,606 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 13.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 5.0.0.Final) starting
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:33,368 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:33,425 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 3) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.3.3.Final
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:33,481 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 9) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:33,607 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:33,650 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO version 3.6.3.Final
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:33,667 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.6.3.Final
^[[0m^[[33m21:07:33,785 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:33,820 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:33,830 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:33,838 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:33,875 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:33,913 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.5.1.Final
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:33,990 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 2 core threads with 16 task threads based on your 1 available processors
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:34,025 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:34,054 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ee] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) WFLYEE0119: The system property 'ee8.preview.mode' is NOT set to 'true'. For provided EE 8 APIs where the EE 8 version of the API differs from what is supported in EE 7, the EE 7 variant of the API will be used. Support for this setting will be removed once all EE 8 APIs are provided and certified.
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:34,061 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:34,257 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 2.0.9.Final starting
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:34,285 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.2.Final
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:34,478 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.7.Final
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:34,481 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.4.9.Final)
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:34,597 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:34,641 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path '/opt/wildfly/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:34,782 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:34,783 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:34,786 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 4 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:34,952 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:35,422 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:35,486 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:35,595 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 0.0.0.0:8080
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:35,612 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:35,793 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYPAT0050: WildFly Full cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
^[[0m^[[33m21:07:35,842 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYDM0111: Keystore /opt/wildfly-13.0.0.Final/standalone/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:35,849 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /opt/wildfly-13.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:35,863 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:35,993 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 0.0.0.0:8443
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:36,122 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.2.1.Final (Apache CXF 3.2.4.jbossorg-1)
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:36,288 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:36,296 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990/management
^[[0m^[[0m21:07:36,296 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990
```

Answer (score 1):

WildFly only presents the admin console on the localhost interface by default for security reasons.

If you want to access the admin console on a particular interface address (say 192.168.15.5), then you must arrange to start WildFly with the following command line option set:

```
  -bmanagement=192.168.15.5
```

Given your "/etc/default/wildfly" configuration you could add the following to accomplish this:

```
  JBOSS_OPTS="-bmanagement=192.168.15.5"
```

BTW, you should never edit the standalone.xml file by hand. This process is error prone and often not repeatable.

Learn how to drive the CLI (which is fully scriptable) or use the admin console instead.

Comment: I added your line but it did not work. Then I returned back to default stanadlone.xml and added your line (and -b 0.0.0.0 as well) it was nothing as well

Answer (score 0):

Locally, local authenticatin mechanism is performed. Remotely login/password authentication is perfomed - you have to add user with add-user.sh